# i am trying to create a little bowling word game but i cant figure out why it doesnt stop

Tags: python

This is my code, i got stuck on the while loop because it just going forever and i cant figure out how to make it stop after putting a certain amount

```
from random import randint

number = randint(1,10)# creates random number
max_movement = 10     # sets max movement
min_movement = 1      # min movement
player_slots = 0      # number of players
player_names = [ ]    # an array of where the players names are held

print("how many players are there?: ")
num_players = int(input())      # put in the amount of players
player_slots = int(num_players) # sets player slots to number of players you put in

for num_players < player_slots: # this is where I'm stuck it just goes on forever
  player_name = input("what are there names?: ")
  player_names.append(player_name)

print(player_names)
```

Comment: `while len(player_names) < player_slots:` makes more sense to me.

Comment: Alright, you changed your code. Does it work now?

Comment: `for` isn't used this way - `while` loop  would be a better fit here...

Comment: i changed it its now len(player_names) < player_slots:

Comment: You never update `num_players` or `player_slots` so the loop never ends.

Comment: why not just append input to `player_names` using for loop of `range(num_players)` if `num_players` and `player_slots` are always equal?  where's the while loop anyway?